# Opening Mime content in Outlook

Tags: outlook, mime, exchangewebservices, msg

I'm looking for a way to get outlook to open a Mime message? It should be possible I just can't seem to find anywhere with examples on how to do it...

Currently we get the mime content and then use Redemption to create a .msg file and then launch that .msg file. I'm looking for a way to just have the mime content from Exchange Web Services managed API and then open it in the Outlook mail item form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We managed to solve the issue by creating the interop Outlook.MailItem manually from the Exchange Web Services mail item, and then calling the .Display() function on the Outlook.MailItem, this also allowed us to use the Outlook.MailItem.SaveAs functionality to save to .msg without having to use any third party libraries.

Edit:
We managed to find a solution in the form of http://www.msoutlook.info/question/354

Opening MIME content in Outlook can be done by saving the file to .eml format and then using the command `C:\\Program Files  (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\Outlook.exe\" /eml @t` where `@t` is the full path to the .eml file you want to open.